# MongoDB connection error getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND Cluster0_shard_name

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having an issue with trying to connect to MongoDB. I'm using mongoose here,

```
console.log("trying here"); // prints

await mongoose.connect(db, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useFindAndModify: false
});

console.log("Mongo DB connected"); // never reached
```

And it throws an error

```
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND cluster0-shard-00-01-abcde.mongodb.net
```

I have never had this error before, it used to work just fine -- not sure where to go from here. I've tried building a new cluster and network access by IP is set to public `0.0.0.0`. It just keeps throwing the same error.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing same error.

How are you using your mongo connection string? and what is your mongoose version?

if your using a latest version of mongoose try using like below string

I changed my string from

```
mongodb://<user>:<password>...
```

to

```
mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>...
```

Answer (score 5):

Note that if you specify `useNewUrlParser: true`, you must specify a port in your connection string, 
like `mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname`. 
The new url parser does not support connection strings that do not have a port, like `mongodb://localhost/dbname`.

[see more info here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html)

one more option, if you use node.js +mongo Atlas:

1. log in  https://cloud.mongodb.com/
2. go to your cluster0 or
   other cluster,
3. click connect... choose connet your application
4. choose node.js and then 2.2.12 or later -

you will get connection string that start with mongodb://

insted of mongodb+srv:// (for node js 3.0 or later)

Answer (score 1):

**check your CONNECTION** :
Quick fix is checking your connection, this error happens while your connection is not stable and it've tried to connect more than 30 sc without any success.

```
//checks connection status
mongoose.connection.on("connected", () => console.log("mongoDb connected!"));
mongoose.connection.on("disconnected", () => console.log("mongoDb disconnected!"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, then I coppied connection string again from my mongodb atlas and rerun the code.

```
 MongoClient.connect('mongodb+srv://user:pass', { useUnifiedTopology: true }).then(
client => {
  console.log('Connected to Database') }).catch(err => {
console.log(err)})
```